# Не заходит в php скрипт!

Tags: php, email

При нажатии на странички кнопки "отправить" запускается скрипт, но первый оператор после `<?php` уже не выполняется , например `<?php echo "OK";`, ничего не выводит!

index.html:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        form {
            margin-left: 35%;
        }

        input {
            margin: 1%;
        }

        body {
            width: 80%;
        }

        .textfield {
            width: 72%;
        }

        .content {
            height: 300px;
            margin-left: 1%;
            resize: vertical;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="sender.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="from" type="text" placeholder="Адрес отправителя" required class="textfield"><br>
    <input name="to" type="text" placeholder="Адрес получателя" required class="textfield"><br>
    <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Тема сообщения" class="textfield"><br>
    <p><textarea class="content" name="message" placeholder="Текст сообщениея" cols="70"></textarea></p>
    <input name="attachments[]" type="file"><br>
    <input name="attachments[]" type="file"><br>
    <input name="attachments[]" type="file"><br>
    <input value="Отправить" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

sender.php

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors",1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "OK";
if ($_POST && isset($_FILES['attachments'])) {
    $recipient_email = $_POST['to'];
    $from_email = $_POST['from'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $attachments = $_FILES['attachments'];
    $file_count = count($attachments['name']); //count total files attached
    $boundary = md5("test");

    if ($file_count > 0) { //if attachment eiists
        //header
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/miied; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";

        //message teit
        $body = "--$boundary\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Type: teit/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
        $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message));

        //attachments
        for ($i = 0; $i < $file_count; $i++) {
            if (!empty($attachments['name'][$i])) {

                if ($attachments['error'][$i] > 0) //eiit script and output error if we encounter any
                {
                    $mymsg = array(1 => "The uploaded file eiceeds the upload_mai_filesize directive in php.ini", 2 => "The uploaded file eiceeds the MAi_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form", 3 => "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded", 4 => "No file was uploaded", 6 => "Missing a temporary folder");
                    die($mymsg[$attachments['error'][$i]]);
                }

                //get file info
                $file_name = $attachments['name'][$i];
                $file_size = $attachments['size'][$i];
                $file_type = $attachments['type'][$i];

                //read file
                $handle = fopen($attachments['tmp_name'][$i], "r");
                $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
                fclose($handle);
                $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); //split into smaller chunks (RFC 2045)

                $body .= "--$boundary\r\n";
                $body .= "Content-Type: $file_type; name="$file_name"\r\n";
                $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$file_name"\r\n";
                $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
                $body .= "i-Attachment-Id: " . rand(1000, 99999) . "\r\n\r\n";
                $body .= $encoded_content;
            }
        }

    } else { //send plain email otherwise
        $headers = "From:" . $from_email . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $from_email . "\n" . "i-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
        $body = $message;
    }

    $sentMail = @mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if ($sentMail) //output success or failure messages
    {
        die('Thank you for your email');
    } else {
        die('Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.');
    }
}
```

Comment: а почему вы думаете что скрипт запускается?

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? функция mail пишется без @

Comment: @ALexander а если с [`@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) написать, то что тогда будет?

Comment: исправьте ошибки в строке 50: FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected '$file_name' (T_VARIABLE) on line number 50

Comment: @teran - полагаю, что выполняться как mail не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, все правильно была ошибка в 50 строке, почему мой php не показывал её

Comment: в 51 такая же ошибка

Comment: @teran Символ `@` перед функцией подавляет вывод ошибок. Т.е. вы даже не узнаете, почему именно не работает функция

Comment: @rjhdby ;) то был вопрос с намеком и ссылкой на документацию :)